# Shading anti-clockwise in QML CircularGaugeStyle using thge fragmentShader property of ShaderEffect

Tags: qt, qml, shader, qtquick2, opengl-3

I want to create a CircularGauge in QML in which the needle moves anti-clockwise and the shader is drawn from +145 deg to needle position.

I implemented a CircularGaugeStyle for the style property of CircularGauge. I used the below code to make the shader effect on the gauge:

```
background: Canvas {
    onPaint: {
        var ctx = getContext("2d");
        ctx.reset();
        paintBackground(ctx);
    }

    ShaderEffect {
        id: gauge
        anchors.fill: parent

        opacity: 0.75

        // Angles measured clockwise from up, in range -pi to pi
        property real angleBase: -2.53073
        property real angle: degToRad(needleRotation)

        vertexShader: "
          uniform highp mat4 qt_Matrix;
          attribute highp vec4 qt_Vertex;
          attribute highp vec2 qt_MultiTexCoord0;
          varying highp vec2 coord;
          void main() {
            coord = qt_MultiTexCoord0;
            gl_Position = qt_Matrix * qt_Vertex;
          }"

        fragmentShader: "
          uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
          uniform highp float angleBase;
          uniform highp float angle;
          varying highp vec2 coord;
          void main() {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
            highp vec2 d=2.0*coord-vec2(1.0,1.0);
            highp float r=length(d);
            if (0.55<=r && r<=0.95) {
              highp float a=atan2(d.x,-d.y);
              if (angleBase<=a && a<=angle) {
                highp float p=(a-angleBase)/(angle-angleBase);
                gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,p,p) * qt_Opacity;
              }
            }
          }"
      }
}
```

In this code the needle moves anti-clock  wise setting the min max angle but the shader effect is drawn clock-wise. I changed the following:

```
property real angleBase: 2.53073 // +145 deg
```

making the baseAngle to +145 deg.

```
if (0.55<=r && r<=0.95) { // the area in gauge that should be painted
  highp float a=atan2(d.y,-d.x); //getting the other side of the angle (pi/2 - theta)
  if (a>=angleBase && angle>=a) { //since we want to draw from +2.5 to needle position (in radians)
    highp float p=(angleBase-a)/(angleBase-angle);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0,0.0,p,p) * qt_Opacity;
  }
}
```

Here is the image of the output with the shader going clock-wise:
[image: QML CircularGauge]

The change in code to draw anti-clockwise is not working. What am I doing wrong? Is my understanding of calculating the atan2 not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how the current `angle` is computed.

In your application 0° seems to be at the top. Keep the angle of -145° (-2.53073)

```
property real angleBase: -2.53073
```

In the original code, the angle (`a`) was computed by `a=atan2(d.x,-d.y);`. If you want to flip that around the y axis, then you the new computation is:

```c
highp vec2  d = coord * 2.0 - vec2(1.0);
highp float r = length(d);
if (0.55<=r && r<=0.95) {
    
    highp float a = atan2(-d.x, -d.y);
    
    if (angleBase <= a && a <= angle) {
    
        highp float p=(a-angleBase)/(angle-angleBase);
        
        // [...]
    }
}
```

In the above algorithm is assumed, that `angle` is in range [-145°, 145°]. Further more the top left `coord` is (0, 0) and the bottom right `coord` is (1, 1)

If `angle` is in range [0°, 290°], then alpha has to be suited to the `baseAngle`:

<s>`if (angleBase <= a && a <= angle) {`</s>

```c
if (angleBase <= a && a <= angle+angleBase ) {
    // [...]
}
```

Comment: flipping around the y axis keeping everything same doesn't help. After doing that the shader starts drawing from the marker 3 in gauge cloclwise and anti-clockwise depending on the position of the needle. I want to start from 0 (+2.5) to needle position.

Comment: tried a=atan2(-d.x, -d.y), and seems like a strange difference lag/lead between the needle and the end point of the shader area. The shader draw starts from -2.5, which is correct but draw upto market 5 when needle at 0, and so on.. here is a small table
Needle: 0, Shader_end: 5, Needle: 1, Shader_end: 4, Needle: 2, Shader_end: 3, Needle: 3, Shader_end: 2,.. so when needle at 0 a 180 deg extra draw and when needle at 2 then 30 deg.

Comment: the angle (needleRotation) is an internal property of the QML object CircularGauge, which the the relative angle from MinAngle to a max value of maxAngle. Here minAngle is set to -145 deg and maxAngle is +145 deg. So alpha is position of needle relative to -145. At the marker 0, the angle is 290 deg and at position 5 angle is 0 deg.

Comment: @dDebug If `alpha` is in range [0, 290] then you have to subtract 145 from alpha: `if (angleBase <= a && a <= angle+angleBase)`. I've extended the answer.

Comment: I' very sorry my last line was incorrect and that created the confusion. The range is -145 to +145 as I mentioned. so at the extreme right angle is 145 deg and extreme left angle is -145 deg and 0 is in the center between the market 2 and 3. So its not 0 to 290 but from -145 to +145. Sorry again to create the confusion.

Comment: @dDebug I can't find any further issue in your code. The algorithm in the answer works fine for me.

Comment: I've to accept your answer. It is working after negating the needleRotation, which makes sense as I'm changing the direction of shader to +145 to -145 but the input angles are -145 to +145. Thanks a lot!